# Multiple imagery of the same tile overlapped with each other

Tags: android, kotlin, tiles, osmdroid

I am implementing a map using my custom tile source but the problem is it is overlapping with imagery maps with my own tile source.[image]

Here is my code for implementing the map with my own tile source.

```
class OurTileSource(url: String) : XYTileSource("plan", 1, 
    20, 128, ".png", arrayOf(url.substring(0, url.indexOfFirst { it == '{' }))) {

   override fun getTileURLString(pMapTileIndex: Long): String {
       val url2 =(baseUrl +"/" +MapTileIndex.getZoom(pMapTileIndex) + 
       "/"
       + MapTileIndex.getX(pMapTileIndex) + "_" 
            + MapTileIndex.getY(pMapTileIndex) + mImageFilenameEnding)
       return url2
   }
}
```

Code for setting up the map

```
if (device.tileTemplate != null) {
        mapView.setTileSource(OurTileSource(device.tileTemplate!!))
        btnMap.visibility = View.GONE
    } else {
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK)
        btnMap.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    val zoom = if (device.tileTemplate != null) 3.0 else 8.0

    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(false)
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false)
    mapView.setScrollableAreaLimitDouble(mapView.boundingBox)
    mapView.controller.setCenter(GeoPoint(device.lat, device.lon))
    mapView.controller.setZoom(zoom)
    mapView.invalidate()
```

Comment: This seems like some failure when loading tiles or wrong tiles on the server (wrong zoomlevel). Maybe try to check your logcat. There may be some errors from osmdroid about urls that failed to load.

Comment: Tiles are correct, it shows correct in IOS version of this app, And there is no error in Log